# Remove any text before the last iteration of a '/' character with javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's assume I have something like this in the DOM:

```
<label>Canvas Mens Shirt / Black / Medium</label>
<label>Canvas Lady's Shirt / Black / Large</label>
```

I want to remove everything occurring before the last `/` in each string. So the final output would be: `<label>Medium</label>` `<label>Large</label>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `replace` with a regular expression. To also deal with the case where you would have more than one such label, use `each` to repeat the operation for all of them:

```js
$('label').each(function () { // When you have more than one label...
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/.*\/\s*/, ""));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Canvas Men's Shirt / Black / Medium</label><br>
<label>Canvas Lady's Skirt / Blue / Small</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this :

```js
var str = $('label').html(); // Canvas Mens Shirt / Black / Medium
var str_array = str.split('/'); // ['Canvas Mens Shirt', 'Black ', 'Medium']
var str_final = '<label>' + str_array[str_array.length - 1].trim() + '</label>'; // Medium
console.log(str_final);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Canvas Mens Shirt / Black / Medium</label>
```

Comment: What about multiple labels?

Comment: that will be little different, but not much. jquery will get an array, then for each item we repeat those codes.